# How can I find geo objects accessible from given address in given time?

Tags: database, google-maps, neo4j, openstreetmap, yandex-api

For example I want to find all restaurants that I can reach from my home in 30 minutes. I already have a database with addresses of all restaurants in town. How can I get the full list of restaurants reachable in given time?
I also want to have the ability to choose transportation: car, public transport, on foot or any other. Do google, yandex or other services gives such an API? I'm also considering neo4j (http://neo4j.com/) and openstreetmap (http://www.openstreetmap.org/) but cant figure out straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [OSM wiki on isochromes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Isochrone). It contains some explanation and lists lots of examples.